# How do I create a trigger in MySQL and run on conditons

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have two tables as described below, I would like to create a trigger to update my `monitor` table with a timestamp when the related posts' `post_status = 'draft'`. However I have two issues:

I have created a query (also below) but I seem it returns an error on line 5 (where the update command is).

The second issue is how will MySQL handle if it cannot find the corresponding `post_id` in my `monitor` table.

Table(s):

```
posts
- id
- name
- post_status

monitor
- id
- post_id
- last_checked
```

MySQL Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_tracker AFTER UPDATE ON posts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.post_status = 'draft' THEN
    UPDATE monitor SET last_checked = NOW() WHERE post_id = UPDATE.id;
END IF;
END;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21229)

Comment: Don't forget to change your `DELIMTER` when defining triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you intend `UPDATE.id` to refer to, but I guess you mean `NEW.id`, which is the id column of the row that spawned this trigger.

All columns of the row that spawned the current trigger are referenced with the `NEW.<column>` syntax.

If your UPDATE matches no rows in the `monitor` table, it has no effect. Just as if you had run an UPDATE with a condition that matches zero rows.